# Why won't my php echo work?

Tags: javascript, php, function, echo

I'm trying to get my php file to call a function in my javascript file. After all I've read about it, it seems that the easiest way is to echo a script back like this:

```
echo "<script language=english> test(); </script>";
```

However my code does seem to work. My php file runs perfectly until the second I write an line of code with echo.

The javascript file is running on my website and the php file on my server. This is the code:

```
function logIn()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // Code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // Code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "LogIn.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function test() {
    alert("test");
}
```

php file:

```
<?php

echo "<script language=javascript> test(); </script>";

?>
```

Can anyone please help me figuring out why my php file won't run when I write an echo line of code?

Comment: is this the code in the javascript file ?

Comment: The language attribute in the script tag tells what *programming* language it is, not what spoken language. Change it to 'text/javascript'.

Comment: the top part is the javascript file the bottom is a separate php file

Comment: `language="english"` makes no sense. Use `type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: have you tried. echo '<script>test();</script>';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing nothing with the response, that is why nothing is happening. Learn about [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).